# LINQ to Entities - WHERE clause to exclude Partially Shipped Orders in my example

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have an Order table. An Order can have multiple items in it, with each item shipping at different times. I want to get the list of all Orders which *excludes* partially shipped or orders. In other words, I need to get the list of all orders that are *completely* shipped. I may know how to do this in T-SQL. But I'm trying to accomplish this with LINQ-to-Entities (EF4/.Net 4.0/C#).

Consider the following Data:

```
PK      OrderID      Item       Status
1       00001        TV         Shipped
2       00001        TABLET     Shipped
3       00002        BLURAYPL   Not Shipped
4       00002        MOBILEPH   Shipped
5       00002        XBOX       Shipped
6       00003        PAPER      Shipped
7       00003        PENCIL     Shipped
```

The goal is to get 00001 and 00003 as output.

Here is what I have so far, obviously simplified :

```
using (MyDBEntities dbcontext = new MyDBEntities())
{
  var WashingtonClients = from a in dbcontext.CustomerMasterTable
                    where a.City == "Washington"
                    select a.CustomerID;

 var ShippedOrdersToWashingtonClients = from o in dbcontext.OrderDetail
                     where WashingtonClients.Contains(o.CustomerID)
                     && o.Status.ToUpper() == "SHIPPED"
                     //how to exclude Partially Shipped orders here???
                     select o.OrderID;
}
```

How to frame the second query in such a way that it excludes orders that have even a single unshipped item in it? Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have fake list with your data:

```
var orderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>
    {
        new OrderDetail{ ID = 1, Item = "TV", OrderID = "00001", Status = "Shipped"},
        new OrderDetail{ ID = 2, Item = "TABLET", OrderID = "00001", Status = "Shipped"},
        new OrderDetail{ ID = 3, Item = "BLURAYPL", OrderID = "00002", Status = "NotShipped"},
        new OrderDetail{ ID = 4, Item = "MOBILEPH", OrderID = "00002", Status = "Shipped"},
        new OrderDetail{ ID = 5, Item = "XBOX", OrderID = "00002", Status = "Shipped"},
        new OrderDetail{ ID = 6, Item = "PAPER", OrderID = "00003", Status = "Shipped"},
        new OrderDetail{ ID = 7, Item = "PENCIL", OrderID = "00003", Status = "Shipped"}
    };
```

Then your linq query should look like this:

```
var result = orderDetails
    .GroupBy(o => o.OrderID)
    .Where(g => g.All(i => i.Status == "Shipped"))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

so that you get a couple of string - `"00001" and "00003"` as a result.

Hence for real query to db you can write something like this:

```
dbContext.OrderDetails
    .Where(o => WashingtonClients.Contains(o.CustomerID))
    .GroupBy(o => o.OrderID)
    .Where(g => g.All(i => i.Status == "Shipped"))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Is this possible with Query Syntax?

Comment: No. `All` doesn't have query analogue.

Comment: You just saved me from writing a very complex stored procedure. Thank you very much.